# Dependency between branches in state tree in Redux

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I have a state object with the following branches (trying to adhere to ["Normalizing the state shape"](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html)):

**Users**

An array of elements like

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Werner"
}
```

originating from some server.

**User locations**

An array of elements like

```
{
  userId: 1,
  latitude: 45,
  longitude: 70
}
```

originating from some server.

**The problem**

The users might change depending on a number of actions: `SET_USERS_ACTION`, `ADD_USER_ACTION`, `DELETE_USER_ACTION`.

Every time something happens to the users, I want to update the user locations (which is an asynchronous operation, as the data needs to come from the server). The *how* of the matter is what I'm struggling with.

Obviously, I can't fetch the user locations in the reducer (when updating the users), as the reducer would no longer be pure in that case.

I might do it in the [thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk), but that would mean I have to add user location considerations to every action creator involving user-actions, which seems like [mixing concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) to me.

Additionally, once an action is added that changes the users array in some way, the developer needs the *remember* to also update the user locations. My experience is that stuff like this will almost always be forgotten at some point.

**Further complications**

To further complicate the matter, we don't *always* need to fetch the locations. Only if a component displaying a map with all users is active, does it make sense to fetch the user locations. Not every action is generated at a place where I know (beforehand) if that component is visible or not. One example is when we receive a notification from the server (with Web Sockets) that a user was added or removed.

What is the best way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to use https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper The benefit of using the `update` helper is that you are able to do many changes at once without touching the state many times. For example:

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

...
case SET_USERS_ACTION:
  return update(
    state,
    {
      users: {
        [idx]: { status: { $set: 'ready' }}
      },
      locations: {
        $push: [{...}]
      }
    }
  );
break;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. I'm afraid I wasn't very clear. The problem isn't updating two branches of the state tree in one go, it was that both need to be updated simultaneously, while both need to be fetched from the server separately. I would rather not "pollute" all the action creators with this new concern. Furthermore, I would like to be able to skip fetching new locations from the server when I'm not going to use these locations anyway.